# How to use database in Heroku

Tags: python, html, django, database, heroku

I am new in web applications and I created first application in django. I decided to deployment my project in Heroku. But I'm so confused about database. I click "Heroku pricing" and I see 4-5 options. Free, Hobby, Standart, etc. And then i see databases options except these options. What is this?? as I said, this is my first applications and I dont know much about web servers. but as far as I know, service providers offer certain packages. These packages include RAM, Storage, Traffic, **Database**, ... etc.

In short, my questions are:

1. Is database included in heroku pricing?
2. I saw "connection 0 of 20" while using the heroku database. Does this mean only 20 users can access the site?
3. When I browsed the Heroku site, I didn't see any storage information in the pricing section. no storage pricing on cloud-based deployments?
4. Can I create a different database outside of the heroku environment and connect it to heroku?

every answer given informs and improving me. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).

Comment: But here is some general information for you: Heroku sells [dynos](https://www.heroku.com/dynos), which are abstracted "VMs" that provide CPU / memory / network for running your application. Databases are entirely separate. Heroku has [its own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) that you can use if you wish, but there are [other database addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) that you can use if you prefer. Heroku's architecture is described on the website 12factor.net, and you might find [factor IV](https://12factor.net/backing-services) relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku PostgreSQL [Hobby Dev pack](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#pricing) is free

- Go to Heroku dashboard
- After creating an app, click on it
- Go to `Resources`
- Under `Add-ons`, in search bar type `postgresql`
- Click on `Heroku postgres`
- In plan name select `Hobby Dev Free`
- Then Click on Heroku Postgres and get your credentials